# Extract US amounts into separate columns

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, pattern-matching

I’m trying to extract amounts denominated in US dollars from a sub-string using a regex expression.  The negative amounts have a ‘CR’ at the end of the string indicating a negative value.  The amounts are contained in a single column csv file with a heading ‘description’. Here are some sample line items:

```
description
Account Total:                    26,458.16          7,476,744.04        7,484,287.03            7,542.99CR           18,915.17
Account Total:                    27,218.61          7,719,293.26        7,740,051.63           20,758.37CR            6,460.24
Account Total:                          .00          7,634,750.07           39,055.35        7,595,694.72          7,595,694.72
Account Total:                    64,249.00                   .00           64,249.00           64,249.00CR                 .00
```

The desired result would ideally be a dataframe with each of the amounts included into separate columns with the following headings: ‘Beg_bal’, ‘Total_cr’, ‘Total_db’, ‘Net_ch’, and ‘Ending_bal’
I have tried the following code but it results in ‘nan’ values:

```
pat=r'^(?P<Beg_bal>\$?(?:\d+,)*\d+\.\d+)\s+(?P<Total_cr>\$?(?:\d+,)*\d+\.\d+)\s+(?P<Total_db>\$?(?:\d+,)*\d+\.\d+)\s+(?P<Net_ch>\$?(?:\d+,)*\d+\.\d+)\s+(?P<Ending_bal>\$?(?:\d+,)*\d+\.\d+)'
df[['Beg_bal','Total_cr','Total_db','Net_ch','Ending_bal']]=df['description'].str.extract(pat)
```

Thanks in advance, any help as always is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is that from a csv file?

Comment: Yes, all lines are contained in a single-column csv file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use `str.split`, remove the first 2 columns as they contains Account and Total: and rename the columns left as desired

```
df_ = df['description'].str.split('\s+', expand=True).iloc[:, 2:]
df_.columns = ['Beg_bal', 'Total_cr', 'Total_db', 'Net_ch', 'Ending_bal']
print (df_)
     Beg_bal      Total_cr      Total_db        Net_ch    Ending_bal
0  26,458.16  7,476,744.04  7,484,287.03    7,542.99CR     18,915.17
1  27,218.61  7,719,293.26  7,740,051.63   20,758.37CR      6,460.24
2        .00  7,634,750.07     39,055.35  7,595,694.72  7,595,694.72
3  64,249.00           .00     64,249.00   64,249.00CR           .00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep='|')
df = df['description'].str.split(r'   *').apply(pd.Series).drop(columns=[0])
df.columns = [['Beg_bal','Total_cr','Total_db','Net_ch','Ending_bal']]
print(df)

     Beg_bal      Total_cr      Total_db        Net_ch    Ending_bal
0  26,458.16  7,476,744.04  7,484,287.03    7,542.99CR     18,915.17
1  27,218.61  7,719,293.26  7,740,051.63   20,758.37CR      6,460.24
2        .00  7,634,750.07     39,055.35  7,595,694.72  7,595,694.72
3  64,249.00           .00     64,249.00   64,249.00CR           .00
```